# How to set id as slug in Bolt CMS?

Tags: url, slug, bolt-cms

How can I use "id" as slug in url?
I am content without the title and Bolt now creates a path such as "slug-cd7k2y"

My contenttype:

```
smsy:
name: SMSy
singular_name: SMS
title_format: id
fields:
    tresc:
        type: textarea
        class: large
        group: content
        required: true
    slug: 
        type: slug
        uses: id
taxonomy: [ kategorie, tags ]
listing_template: listing.twig
listing_records: 10
default_status: publish
sort: -datepublish
recordsperpage: 10
show_on_dashboard: true
```

Answer (score 3):

There are problems with using numeric slugs, as records are available via both their slug and record ID.

That said, there was a [change committed](https://github.com/bolt/bolt/issues/4770) to both stable and development branches this week that will first appear in Bolt 2.2.18 sometime soon that optionally allows the use of numeric slugs.